# How Can I Insert A Carriage Return Linefeed Every X Characters With Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a data file with a fixed record length. There are no carriage returns or line feeds delimiting the records. How can I insert a carriage return linefeed pair at every X characters using Notepad++(where X is the record length)?

Comment: What is the size of your input file?

Comment: @idealmachine: The file I am working on is 486 KB with 750 character records.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This isn't a task suited to Notepad++, particularly with large input files. Using Windows PowerShell (available for free from Microsoft for Windows XP and Windows Vista, and included with Windows 7), you could do this with:

```
(gc in.txt) -replace ".{750}" , "$&`r`n" | sc out.txt
```

Comment: I am new to PowerShell. Could you break down the various elements of the command and comment what they do?

Comment: @DaveB
1. Parens are evaluated first, wherein gc command gets content from the file (in.txt).  2. replace command does a replace, taking first argument ("." for any character, {750} for 750 times), and replacing with second (found string ($) and tacks on carriage return+line feed (`r`n)).   3. This is then sent aka piped ("|") to the next statement.   4. sc command then sets content to the file parameter (out.txt).

Answer (score 76):

I appreciate that it's not ideal, but I'm surprised no one offered this as a pure N++ solution

In a regular expression find/replace

Find:

```
(.{750})
```

Replace:

```
$1\r\n
```

Roughly translated as...

Find:

> 750 instances of any character and remember the characters.

Replace:

> The 750 characters we just remembered followed by a new line.

Although, to be honest, I'd stick to the powershell approach for anything more than a one-off run.

Comment: Google brought me here. This worked great for a one-off document I had to split and diff! Thank you very much.

Comment: This!  ...is the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Notepad++ v5.8.3 has this command: first select the whole file; then

Edit -> Line Operations -> Split Lines

This splits lines so that they fit exactly in the current window. As far as I can see, you have to use the mouse to resize the window to the width that you want.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore.  :'(  They get split at the light blue line no matter how wide your window is

Comment: Looks like there *is* an option to set the blue line https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/3/how-does-split-lines-work.

Answer (score 5):

For V6.3

1. Frame Window to Text Length
2. Highlight [ALL Text] >>Edit  > Select ALL
3. Edit> LineOperations > SplitLine

Save Document under NEW NAME.

Answer (score 2):

1. Type the number of characters you want on each line, select it, and then choose Edit → Cut.
2. Edit → Select All, then TextFX → TextFX Edit → ReWrap Text to (Clipboard or 72) width
3. TextFX → TextFX Edit → Trim Trailing Spaces

Comment: My records are 750 characters. After following your instructions, I am left with records of various lengths. Testing with a length of 10 characters leaves me with lines as short as 1 after trimming off the trailing spaces :( I am using version 5.7 of Notepad++.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  It always wraps to 72 characters regardless of what's in the clipboard

Comment: NPPTextFX2 is a replacement for the now obsolete TextFX. It is available in the Notepad++ Plugins Admin and it works just as described in the answer. If you copy the number 100 to the clipboard, it wraps to that number of characters.